# Why does the program do this? C++

Tags: c++

So I have the code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace::std;
int main() {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;
    while (a < 100) {
        a = a + b; 
        b = a + b;
        cout << a << endl;
        cout << b << endl;
    }
}
```

What it does is print the fibonacci sequence up to 100. But, when I make "a" bigger, say, (OVER 9000!!!) 10 billion, it just prints out random numbers it seems. Why does it do this?

Comment: [Integer Overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)

Comment: 10 billion might be larger than can be represented by an `int` on your platform. Have you tried `long` and, if C++11, `long long`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This probably happens when you exceed the range of an integer (probably 2,147,483,647 on Windows 32-bit).  Try changing the types to `long long` and see if you get more accurate results to a larger range.  Alternatively, you could change add `unsigned` to the type because the fib. sequence is strictly positive, so that'll double the range of values.

This is architecture dependent, but using ranges from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz(v=vs.80).aspx, your ranges would be:

```
int: [–2,147,483,648, 2,147,483,647]
unsigned int: [0, 4,294,967,295]
long long: [–9,223,372,036,854,775,808, 9,223,372,036,854,775,807]
unsigned long long: [0, 18,446,744,073,709,551,615]
```

Edit: totally off-topic, but thanks for putting me over 1k you glorious voting bastards!

Comment: Since he is not using decimals he should rather use something like an int64 ( long long )

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your [integer values overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow), because you start assigning values larger than an int in C++ supports.  For example, on Microsoft compilers, the [largest int value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is 2,147,483,647.

In order to support this directly, you'd likely need some form of [Big Integer library](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/), which provides support for arbitrarily large integer values.

Answer (score 0):

This is called [integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)

Answer (score 0):

When the programmer selects a data type, such as `int`, it is the programmer's responsibility to ensure the numbers stored *fit* in that data type. On typical machines, an `int` can hold a value up to about 2.14 billion. If you go over that, you get nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Youre using an `int` which means it is an `32 Bit Integer` - Now with some math ( `2^32` ) we come to the conclusion that you cant save any values greater than 2,147,483,647.

Try a `long long`/`int64` - this should be enough !